# How to perform digitsum for a negative integer input until a single digit is obtained?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
def add_digits():
    num=int(input("Enter  "))
    return (num - 1) % 9 + 1 if num > 0 else 0

print(add_digits())
```

How to make this work for negative input? Please do help. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should have your `add_digits` function take in the value as a parameter rather than getting it from the user; that'll make it easier to build on it:

```
def add_digits(num: int) -> int:
    return (num - 1) % 9 + 1 if num > 0 else 0

print(add_digits(int(input("Enter "))))
```

Now you have a much simpler problem to solve: how do we make sure that when this function gets passed a negative number, it returns the negative of the result of the corresponding positive number?  That's very easy to express as a simple recursive call at the beginning:

```
def add_digits(num: int) -> int:
    if num < 0:
        return -add_digits(-num)
    return (num - 1) % 9 + 1 if num > 0 else 0
```

```
assert add_digits(123456) == 3    # ok
assert add_digits(-123456) == -3  # ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the absolute value of `num`?

```
def add_digits(num):
    if num == 0:
        return 0
    elif num > 0:
        return (num - 1) % 9 + 1 
    else:
        return -( (abs(num) - 1) % 9 + 1 )

num = int(input("Enter  "))
print(add_digits(num))
```